# Excel returns dates instead of computed value

Tags: c#, excel

So I have an excel importer that takes the data from an excel worksheet and fills a DataTable, then I insert it into a SQL table. I've used it for thousands of imports but for this one worksheet it won't pull the correct value of the cell from the worksheet. My function is returning a value like "1/4/1900 7:42:25AM" when the cell actually contains "$4.32" and returns empty for a cell header value of "Price per unit". The formula for the cell is something like "=(J9*(1-K9)*(1-M9))". The entire column is formatted as "Currency".

I have no idea what's going on so any insight is appreciated.

The code to get the excel worksheet -> DataTable:

```
DataTable dt;
        try
        {
            if (FileInUse(filename))
            {
                e.Result = false;
                Core.ShowExclamation("The file is already open. Please save and close the file before continuing.");
                return;
            }

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;""");
            string sheet = GetExcelSheetNames(con)[0];

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sheet + "]", con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
```

The code to return some values:

```
            string foo = dt.Rows[5][13].ToString() + "\r\n";
            foo += dt.Rows[6][13].ToString() + "\r\n";
            foo += dt.Rows[7][13].ToString() + "\r\n";
            foo += dt.Rows[8][13].ToString() + "\r\n";
            foo += dt.Rows[9][13].ToString() + "\r\n";
            foo += dt.Rows[10][13].ToString();
            Core.ShowInfo(foo);
```

---

```
Returns:                                        Should Returns:
12/30/1899 12:00:00 AM                          0.00%
9/27/2013 12:00:00 AM                           9/27/2013
{}                                              Reseller Price Per Unit
1/4/1900 7:42:25 AM                             $4.32
1/4/1900 7:42:25 AM                             $4.32
3/10/1901 10:23:42 AM                           $435.43
```

Comment: Excel internally stores dates as floating-point numbers.  There's no type information, just the display format that controls meaning.

Comment: Certainly, I posted an article about how the OleDBDataAdapter determines the data types of a column though which is where the problem turned out to be. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found this article from a question asked by Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen

http://neosblogs.blogspot.com/2008/06/how-jet-ole-db-decide-excel-column-type.html

The fix:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1""");
```

Just had to set "**IMEX=1**"